# Difference in the lenghts of two lists

Tags: python, list, time-series, series

I have this function which calculates the period under water of a series (sp_500):

```
def period_under_water(series: pd.Series):

max_to_date = np.empty(len(series))
max_to_date[0] = series.iloc[0]

idx_max = np.empty(len(series), dtype='int')
idx_max[0] = 0

T = len(series.index)

HMW = []
control = False

for t in range(1, T):
    current_val = series.iloc[t]
    
    if current_val < max_to_date[t-1]:
        max_to_date[t] = max_to_date[t-1]
        idx_max[t] = idx_max[t-1]
        
        if not control:
            HMW.append(series.iloc[t-1])
            control = True
        
    else:
        max_to_date[t] = current_val
        idx_max[t] = t
        control = False

starting_dates = series[series.isin(HMW)].index.tolist()

rel_loss = (max_to_date - series) / max_to_date
ending_dates = []

for i in range(1, len(rel_loss)):
    if rel_loss[i] == 0 and rel_loss[i-1] > 0:  # Condition for the end of drawdown
        ending_dates.append(series.index[i])
  
return HMW, starting_dates, ending_dates
```

The problem is that the length of starting_dates (240) does not match the one of ending_dates (234). I would expect them to be equal or, at most, starting_dates = 240 and ending_dates = 239. What am I doing wrong?

HMW stands for High Water Marks, which are points in the price index at which the index value is greater than any previous index value and is followed by a loss. starting_dates is a list that stores all the HMWs dates and ending_dates is a list that stores the dates when HMWs were surpassed again.

To get the same series I am coding with code this:

```
start_date = "2000-1-1"
end_date = "2022-12-31"

sp_500 = yf.download("SPY", start = start_date, end = end_date)[["Adj Close"]]
sp_500 = sp_500.squeeze()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ending_dates = []

for i in range(1, len(rel_loss)):
    if rel_loss[i] == 0 and rel_loss[i-1] > 0:
        ending_dates.append(series.index[i])
    elif rel_loss[i] > 0 and rel_loss[i-1] > 0:
        ending_dates.append(series.index[i])

ending_dates = list(set(ending_dates))
ending_dates.sort()
```

This codle fixes up your condition where rel_loss[i] == 0 but also when rel_loss[i] > 0 and rel_loss[i-1] > 0.

By using set, we can ensure that ending_dates contains unique values, and sort ensures the dates are in ascending order.

Give this code a try, if it doesn't work, please tell me and I'll help further.

Comment: Thanks for helping but the error persists. Now ending_dates = 5302, because with your adjustments it basically saves all the dates in variable rel_loss

Comment: Ah, that doesn't make sense, let me check it again and edit my answer sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this code:

```
def period_under_water(series: pd.Series):
max_to_date = series.cummax()
rel_loss = (max_to_date - series) / max_to_date

HMW = []
starting_dates = []
ending_dates = []
control = False

for i in range(len(rel_loss)):
    if rel_loss[i] > 0 and not control:
        HMW.append(series.iloc[i])
        starting_dates.append(series.index[i-1])
        control = True
    elif rel_loss[i] <= 0 and control:
        ending_dates.append(series.index[i])
        control = False

if control:
    ending_dates.append(series.index[-1])

return HMW, starting_dates, ending_dates
```